# Fade in internal navigation buttons using jQuery

Tags: jquery, hover, each, fade

I have a series of photos on a page in an unordered list. I want to hover on a photo, have up/down arrows fade in, and then click on one of the arrows to go either up/down to the next photo.

It works except when I hover on a photo, the up/down arrows appear on every photo. I'd like the arrows to appear only on the photo I'm actually hovering on.

Here's the code so far:

```
$('section li').hover(function() {
   $('section nav').fadeIn();
},
function() {
   $('section nav').fadeOut();
});

<section>
   <ul>
      <li id="photo-0">
         <img src="img.png" />
         <nav>
            <a class="down" href="#photo-1">down</a>
         </nav>
      </li>
      <li id="photo-1">
         <img src="img.png" />
         <nav>
            <a class="down" href="#photo-2">down</a>
            <a class="up" href="#photo-0">up</a>
         </nav>
      </li>
   </ul>
</section>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your code to this:

```
$('section li').hover(function() {
   $(this).find('nav').fadeIn();
},
function() {
   $(this).find('nav').fadeOut();
});
```

This takes the `li` that you are currently hovering over and finds just the `nav` in that specific `li` and only animates that one.

Comment: @NickJ.  Since I see you are new here to asking questions, I'll remind you that you should click on the checkmark to the left of the answer that help you the most and you can also reward the answerer with an upvote.